# How to display the Media Library Items Upload date

Tags: images, media

I have a product image catalogue and i'd like to display the Uploaded date of the image:

I can see on the media library it displays on-top of the item: Uploaded on: April 15, 2021 as an exmaple but how do I access that? in my templated files

Answer (score 0):

If you have the attachment ID, you can just use [`get_the_date()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/):

```
<?php echo get_the_date( '', $attachment_id ); ?>
```

If you leave the first argument blank, e.g. `''`, then it will use the date format from settings. If you don't want that, then provide a [PHP date format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).